# discord.py: Can i make it so i, the bot owner, can use any command in any server regardless of whether i have the required perms or not?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make it so people with manage_messages perms can use the command, plus me, the owner of the bot, can use the command even if i don't have manage_messages perms. Here's the code i have so far:

```
@commands.command()
  @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = True)
  async def spam(self, ctx, msg, delay: int):
    global on
    on = True
    while on:
      await ctx.send(msg)
      await asyncio.sleep(int(delay))
  @spam.error
  async def spam_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send(f"Missing argument(s). Proper usage: `{prefix}spam <message to spam> <delay in seconds>`")
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("Missing permission(s): Manage_Messages")
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
      await ctx.send("The delay must be an integer")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

```py
@commands.check_any(commands.is_owner(), commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
@commands.command()
# command  here
```

### References:

- [check_any](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=check_any#discord.ext.commands.check_any) returns true if any one of the check returns true
- [is_owner](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=is_owner#discord.ext.commands.is_owner) returns true if the author is the owner of the bot.

Note:
**Not sure of this** but, if you use your bot to bypass mod commands and use it yourself, it might be against ToS.